# why jquery mouseover on dropdown options doesn't work on Chrome/Webkit?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, mouseover

I'm writing a simple code to display some description as user hovers over a dropdown options. But no luck with getting it to work in Chrome. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```
$('#dropdown option').mouseover(function (e) {
    $('.option-desciption').show();
    console.log('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one :

```
$('#dropdown').on("mouseover", function (e) {
    $('.option-desciption').show();
    console.log('test');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/